# Protractor does not find chromedriver: The driver executable does not exist:

Tags: angularjs, selenium, integration-testing, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get Protractor up and running following the official [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

The command

```
webdriver-manager start
```

seems to run smoothly:

```
webdriver-manager start
seleniumProcess.pid: 22169
Apr 23, 2014 10:27:46 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver
10:27:46.959 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-462
10:27:46.960 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64
10:27:46.968 INFO - v2.41.0, with Core v2.41.0. Built from revision 3192d8a
10:27:47.021 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: MAC
10:27:47.059 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: <link deleted>
10:27:47.059 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
10:27:47.060 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
10:27:47.060 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
10:27:47.061 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
10:27:47.092 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@4cc39a20
10:27:47.092 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
10:27:47.096 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
10:27:47.096 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1d5a0305
```

However, running

```
protractor /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/example/conf.js
```

as suggested leads to errors:

```
protractor /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/example/conf.js 
Using the selenium server at <link deleted>

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1702
  throw error;
        ^
UnknownError: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver
at <anonymous>
```

and the old window throws exception:

```
10:30:19.106 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'Dmitris-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '172.20.10.2', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:177)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:90)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:96)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:63)
10:30:19.110 WARN - Exception: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, had to break due to timeout, however, now it says: `selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.`

Comment: why is setting up test environments always seem to be such a pain. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete that un-completed zip file(chromedriver_x.xx.zip), and you need it execute the update again.
The folder will look like this:

> chromedriver
>
> chromedriver_2.10.zip
>
> selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar

and everything goes well.

Comment: I ended up manually downloading the zip and placing that into the folder. Somehow the update was failing to extract.

Comment: More specifically, Check that the value of "chromedriver" version inside the config.json in node_modules/protractor, matches the zip file name, e.g: "chromedriver": "2.21" => chromedriver_2.21.zip. thats the only thing that fixed it for me.

Comment: @Fanchi, No such file in node_modules/protractor

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because of the latest update for chromedriver. If you are using protractor, then a easy way to fix the problem is just run this

webdriver-manager update

Its working fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users:

Under the 'angular-phonecat' folder, run `npm install chromedriver`. This will install the chrome driver into the folder `node_modules/chromedriver`. After this, you should modify the `test/protractor-conf.js`, pointing it to the new chromedriver folder, by adding this line:

`chromeDriver:'../node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver',`

Finally, you will run successfully the command `npm run protractor` (don't forget that `npm start` should be run first).

Comment: Works fine in my IDE, but Jenkins tries to find his own Chromedriver (in /var/lib/jenkins/tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.ext). I wonder how I could override this...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my environment (Mac OS X 10.8.5).

After struggling it for more than an hour, I finally installed the older version (1.4.0) of the protractor and it works very fine.

`npm install -g protractor@1.4.0`

If you would use grunt task grunt-protractor-webdriver, you should use the version 0.1.9 which is working properly in my env. Its 0.2.0 version doesn't work for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In protractor-config you need to specify the chrome driver path. For example
 chromeDriver: 'path',

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, this setting in `conf.js` seems to be ignored: `  chromeDriver: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'` when I run `protractor conf.js`

Comment: If you added grunt-protractor-runner dependency in package.json file. The chrome driver downloaded in the following path 'node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin, when you execute webdrive-manager update. Or other wise you can instll other dependencies chromDriver, Selenium and specify that appriote path.

Comment: Solved it but with some real hacking: Renamed `chromedriver_2.9.zip` inside `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/` (possibly not necessary), re-installed `npm install selenium-webdriver -g`, and `sudo npm install -g protractor`, then `selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar` was corrupted, so I manually downloaded it from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/, and replaced, then ran `webdriver-manager update` and waited for that to end, after which `chromedriver` was unzipped, after which everything worked as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem with not being able to run my protractor tests, after updating MacOSX to el Capitan.

I was able to solve the problem by re-installing the chromedriver on the system.
Try running "**sudo npm install chromedriver**" from your console. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue when building/testing the same tutorial. In the project selenium folder I had chromedriver_2.13.zip, but no chromedriver exec file. I tried unzipping it directly, but no joy.

So I installed protractor globally using `sudo npm install -g protractor`, which installs the files at usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/ (on a Mac). In that folder the chromedriver executable did exist, so I copy/pasted into the project selenium folder and now protractor runs as expected using the `npm run protractor` command from inside the project folder.

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem on my Mac.
I solved it by:

Downloading the latest chromedriver manually.  Copying it to the desired location (protactor/selenium/).  Try again - worked