# Getting error in error.js

Tags: protractor

I am getting an error in error.js- under repo

> Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js

The error which I got is:

> super(opt error) {

**"WebDriverError : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;"**

I have created just two files one is conf.js and another is test_spec.js.

**test_spec.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://angular.org/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('AngularJS');
  });
});
```

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    //The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  //Here we specify the name of the specs files.
  specs: ['test_spec.js']
}
```

I want to mention here that i have all the files needed under my selenium folder which is chromedriver.exe, chromedriver_2.21.zip and selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0 according to my config.json but still i m getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please follow the below steps and check if it solve your problem.

Open terminal and enter the following commands.

```
1.npm install -g protractor
2.webdriver-manager update
3.webdriver-manager start
4.protractor  path-to-config.json file
```

Comment: already did, but still got the same error. And the steps you wrote, is the default steps of installation.\

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240397/protractor-does-not-find-chromedriver-the-driver-executable-does-not-exist] here you can find some other solutions for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try use this protractor.conf.js

```
 exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['spec/**/*[sS]pec.js'],
/*
 * If u want to use only one browser
  capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome"
  },


   * By this you can use multiBrowser
   *
   */

  multiCapabilities:[
    {
      'browserName' : 'chrome'
    },
    /*{
      'browserName' : 'firefox'
    },
    {
      'browserName' : 'internet explorer',
      'platform' : 'ANY',
      'version' : '11'
    },
    {
      'browserName' : 'phantomjs'
    },
    */
  ],
  /*
  * Force protractor to use only one browser at a time
  */
  maxSessions: 1,
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    showTiming: true,
    isVerbose:true,

  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    /*
     Set browser window size
     */
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1920, 1080);


  },

  /*
   Set your app's main URL here, so you can use relative urls along the tests
   */
  baseUrl: 'http://url_to_app.com',

};
```