# E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location in Jenkins(linux)

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am new to Jenkins

I am trying to run Angular protractor test cases in Jenkins linux environment. Those are running fine in the Windows machine.

I am running selenium server using webdriver-manager running on http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
I have also installed xvfb plugin in Jenkins, still the issue remains the same.

Protractor.config.js

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--disable-browser-side-navigation']
    }
  },
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
directConnect: false,
```

I am getting following error in Jenkins

[04:31:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[04:31:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[04:32:15] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '1031ca678034', ip: '172.17.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.93-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[04:32:15] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '1031ca678034', ip: '172.17.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.93-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse
 (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver
 (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/angular-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[04:32:15] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 199
npm ERR! angular-protractor@0.0.0 e2e: `protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 199

Comment: "driver.version: unknown" seems like a good place to start.  Check chromedriver path/permissions.

Comment: this thread seems to indicate that "webdriver-manager update" will solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240397/protractor-does-not-find-chromedriver-the-driver-executable-does-not-exist

Comment: @pcalkins tried with webdriver-manager update, It didn't work